# javax.validation.constraints.@Max not working as request param

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, request, max

Tried to add @Max validation for the sizes request parameter. However, it seems whatever value I put in will be valid.

A simple controller method in a spring boot application.

```
    @GetMapping("/all")
public String getAll(@RequestParam @Max(value=20, message = "should be less than 20") int sizes) {
    if (sizes > 20) {
        return "Pass but not valid";
    }
    return "Valid";
}
```

when request param sizes is 21, I get Pass but not valid rather error message
http://localhost:8080/all?sizes=21

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

dit you put @Validated above you class?

Comment: yes. import from import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

Comment: by the way, can @Validated only work with controller class? What about spring boot application class?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer ([Spring Controller: RequestParam not validated despite @Valid and @Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719825/spring-controller-requestparam-not-validated-despite-valid-and-size#53720225)) helpful for exactly this question.

Basically, it says that:

1. `MethodValidationPostProcessor` needs to be added to a configuration.
2. `@Validated` annotation needs to be added on top of the controller class.
3. Possibly some exceptions like `ConstraintViolationException` or `MethodArgumentNotValidException` will need to be handled if customized responses are wanted.

For this setup to run, I had to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` like it's said in this answer: ["The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found" preventing startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483120/the-bean-validation-api-is-on-the-classpath-but-no-implementation-could-be-foun)